# Passing the results of a query to a parameter in a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to get the results of a stored procedure by passing the results of the query to my parameter.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [DWH].[spAMBSiteAssetCountReport] 
    @Areaname, @SiteType, @EquipmentClass, @AssetStatus
    @MaintenanceLocation varchar(Max),
    @FLClassDescription varchar(max),
    @EquipmentClass varchar(max),
    @AssetStatus varchar(max)
As
Begin
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF -- to suppress warning "string or binary data would be truncated"

    SELECT  
        EC.ClassDescription, FL.Site, 
        SUBSTRING(FL.Site, CHARINDEX('-',FL.Site)+1,LEN(FL.Site)) SiteNo, 
        FL.SiteDesc, FL.FunctionalLocation, FL.Parish, 
        ST.SiteTypeName FLClassDescription, FL.MaintenanceLocationDesc,
        Count(1) AS AssetCount
    FROM    
        DWH.DimFunctionalLocation AS FL 
    INNER JOIN 
        DWH.DimEquipment AS EQ ON EQ.FunctionalLocationKey = FL.DW_FunctionalLocation_Key  
    INNER JOIN 
        DWH.DimEquipmentDetail AS EQD ON EQ.DW_Equipment_Key = EQD.EquipmentKey
    INNER JOIN 
        DWH.DimEquipmentClass AS EC ON EC.DW_EquipmentClass_Key = EQD.DW_EquipmentDetail_Key
    INNER JOIN 
        DWH.DimSiteType ST ON FL.SiteTypeKey = ST.DW_SiteType_Key
    INNER JOIN 
        (select Item 
         from DWH.fnSplit(@FLClassDescription,',')) AS DNO ON (FL.SiteTypeKey = DNO.Item OR @FLClassDescription ='-1')
    INNER JOIN 
        (select Item from DWH.fnSplit(@MaintenanceLocation,',')) AS ML ON (FL.MaintenanceLocationKey = ML.Item OR @MaintenanceLocation ='-1')
    INNER JOIN 
        (select Item from DWH.fnSplit(@EquipmentClass,',')) AS FLC ON (EC.DW_EquipmentClass_Key = FLC.Item OR @EquipmentClass ='-1')
    INNER JOIN 
        (select Item from DWH.fnSplit(@AssetStatus,',')) AS EQC ON ((EQD.CharacteristicName = EQC.Item AND ISNULL(LTRIM(RTRIM(EQD.CHARCharacteristicValue)),'') <> '')  OR  @AssetStatus ='All')
    WHERE 
        FL.FLClassDescription IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY 
        EC.ClassDescription, FL.Site, FL.SiteDesc, 
        FL.FunctionalLocation, FL.Parish, ST.SiteTypeName, 
        FL.MaintenanceLocationDesc
END
```

I get results when I run the query but I need to pass the results to my parameter to get only distinct values for Equipment Class. The exec statement is below:

```
Exec DWH.spAMBSiteAssetCountReport @MaintenanceLocation=N'366,367,332,362,3,360,331,365,361,364,357,396,2,406,371,4,368,369,370,333,394,358,359,395,355,353,354,335,363,356,397,352,349,348,351,350,347,372,373,374,377,375,376,382,386,383,387,384,389,381,391,378,385,379,380,388,390',@FLClassDescription=N'3,4,5,2,1',@EquipmentClass = AssetCount,@AssetStatus=N'All'
```

I get a syntax error when trying to execute the stored procedure using the Asset Count as a valued parameter. Any help on this would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Your parameters are just varchars, so what is "AssetCount" in your procedure call?

Answer (score 0):

First, you declare the @AssetStatus parameter twice.

Second, you alias the count column as 'AssetCount', but don't use it anywhere else, so I'm not sure why you think that is causing a syntax error.

Lastly, you ask:

"I am trying to get the results of a stored procedure by passing the results of the query to my parameter."

What does this mean?  Are you trying to recursively call a stored procedure from itself?  Or are you trying to pass the results of another query INTO this stored procedure?  More detail will help!  If you respond with a comment I will try to help you along with this one - whatever your problem is, I don't think it'll be difficult to solve.

Comment: @PhilipHerman no problem - I see that you aren't providing datatypes for your first four parameters - and you're missing a comma after the fourth.  That will throw a syntax error for sure.